# Why would the session ID entropy only be half of the length of the session ID?

Tags: session-management, random, entropy

On [this page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_ID_Entropy) on the OWASP website, there is a sentence about session id entropy I find quite strange:

> The session ID value must provide at least 64 bits of entropy (if a good PRNG is used, **this value is estimated to be half the length of the session ID**).

What I understand is that if your session id is made of 128 random bits (given by a good PNRG), then what you get is **only 64 bits of entropy**.

I thought that if you get 128 random bits from a good PNRG, you could expect to get something very close to 128 bits of entropy. Did I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit "`if your session id is made of 128 random bits`" is the misunderstanding.

If your session id is 128 bits long, then that is **not** 128 random bits - it is probably only about 64 random bits, encoded as a 128 bit string.

Remember, your session id is not a number - it is a string identifier, that *might* be representing a number.
If the session id is constructed as a hexadecimal number, represented in string form - then each random byte would take up TWO characters in the session id string. This is where that "half the length" comes from in that quote.
However note the previous section on that page - there are other implementations (such as ASP.NET), where the random bits are not represented directly in string-hexadecimal, but are instead base-64 encoded - which results in only 1/3 size increase (or 25% of bits are not random). In which case, 160-bit session id actually gives 120 random bits.

**TL;DR: if your session id is 128 bits long, not all of those are random.**

Answer (score 0):

The actual entropy that you can expect from a 128 bit string is equivalent to entropy from a set of 2^64 different bit strings with 50% chance of collision. This is because of a concept called [**Birthday Paradox**](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-birthday-paradox/) (Not exactly a paradox but that is how it is called).
**Explanation:** 
With 128 bits you have 2^128 different strings (different session ids). But with just 2^64 + 1 different guesses you have a 50% chance of guessing the corrent session id. That is why we use the numerator for representing the entropy of a 128-bit string (session id). For a more clear explanation [see this video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/identifying-security-vulnerabilities/lecture/G2ja3/session-management-threat-bruteforce-session-ids).